# Really struggling with nginx rewrites to https

Tags: nginx, rewrite, https

I hope someone can help.

I am new to ubuntu and nginx and have set up my own server (with the help of various guides around the internet)

Here is my setup.

ubuntu server 14.04, nginx, php5 fpm, static IP, working website in the default  (didn't feel I needed to setup virtual hosts)

Bearing in mind that a few weeks ago I knew absolutely nothing about nginx or even that it existed so I have not done bad and learnt a lot in the process.

What I want is accessible from the www

My IP 212.100.10.100 (for example purposes)

My domain `https://example.com`

WWW version `https://www.example.com`

I have my SSL certificate setup correctly and nginx is happy with it

I am trying to redirect all traffic to https:// but I am having mixed results IE either I access my site and it downloads pages or I get an error 403 I think saying that the requests are being sent to a https port. When that happens I can access my site fine with https

Here is my nginx site config edited please ignore the # I have been trying stuff :) at this time my site works fine on http:// with this config and I can access via my IP as well

```
server {
    listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name 212.100.10.100 example.com www.example.com;
#   return         301 https:// $example.com$request_uri;
        root /var/www/public_html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
#}

#server {
#   listen 80;
#   server_name www.example.com
#   return      301 https:// $example.com$request_uri;
#        root /var/www/public_html;
#        index index.php index.html index.htm;
#}

#server {
#        listen 443 ssl;
#        listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on;
#   server_name example.com;

#   root /var/www/public_html;
#   index index.php index.html index.htm;

       ######HTTPS..

#       ssl on;
#       ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.cer;
#       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;
#       ssl_session_timeout 5m;

#       ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

   # Add perfect forward secrecy
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#   ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';

   # Add HSTS
#        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

    # Basic web server configuration.
        index        index.php
        #access_log   off;
        client_max_body_size  1G;

    # GZIP static content not processed by IPB.
    gzip  on;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 3;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript ap$
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

# Set up rewrite rules.
    location / {
        try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
    location ~^(/page/).*(\.php)$ {
        try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    # Stub Status module
    location /server_status {
        stub_status on;
        #allow 127.0.0.1;
        #deny all;
    }

    # Deny access to hidden files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny  all;
    }

    # IP.Board PHP/CGI Protection
    location ~^(/uploads/).*(\.php)$ {
        deny     all;
    }
    location ~^(/hooks/).*(\.php)$ {
        deny     all;
    }
    location ~^(/cache/).*(\.php)$ {
        deny     all;
    }
    location ~^(/screenshots/).*(\.php)$ {
        deny     all;
    }
    location ~^(/downloads/).*(\.php)$ {
        deny     all;
    }
    location ~^(/blog/).*(\.php)$ {
        deny     all;
    }
    location ~^(/public/style_).*(\.php)$ {
        deny     all;
    }

    # Caching directives for static files.
    location ~^(/uploads/profile/).*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires    1d;
    }
    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml|htm|txt|swf|cur)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires    1w;
    }

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php;
                # With php5-cgi alone:
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 8k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

    location /phpmyadmin {
        auth_basic "Admin Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 240;

    }

###HTTPS REWRITES

#
# Rewrite http requests to https
#
#server {
#  listen 80;
#  server_name example.com;
#  return 301 https:// example.com$request_uri;
#}

#
# Rewrite requests for http:// www.example.com to https:// example.com
#
#server {
#  listen 80;
#  server_name www.example.com;
#  return 301 https:// example.com$request_uri;
#}

}
```

When I try configuring it I have had issues everytime and it seems that if I don't have IP address and domain in the server name directive then when I try accessing them I get the standard "welcome to nginx" Page which suggests that it might be another config I am missing

EDIT..

Thank you for your help this is the new setup and it seems to work.

I was only commenting out to keep my site online when I was trying to get this working.

Thanks again :) If anyone spots anything I am doing wrong I would be glad to hear.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https:// example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /var/www/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    ######HTTPS..

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.cer;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;
   ssl_session_timeout 5m;

   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

# Add perfect forward secrecy
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';

# Add HSTS
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

# Basic web server configuration.
    index        index.php
    #access_log   off;
    client_max_body_size  1G;

# GZIP static content not processed by IPB.
gzip  on;
gzip_static on;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 3;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript ap$
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

# Set up rewrite rules.
location / {
    try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
location ~^(/page/).*(\.php)$ {
    try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

# Stub Status module
location /server_status {
    stub_status on;
    #allow 127.0.0.1;
    #deny all;
}

# Deny access to hidden files
location ~ /\. {
    deny  all;
}

# IP.Board PHP/CGI Protection
location ~^(/uploads/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/hooks/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/cache/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/screenshots/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/downloads/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/blog/).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}
location ~^(/public/style_).*(\.php)$ {
    deny     all;
}

# Caching directives for static files.
location ~^(/uploads/profile/).*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires    1d;
}
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml|htm|txt|swf|cur)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires    1w;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            # With php5-cgi alone:
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 8k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

location /phpmyadmin {
    auth_basic "Admin Login";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_read_timeout 240;

}
}
```

Comment: Having everything commented out will definitely cause problems.

Comment: I know it is just easy while I get everything working as I remove comments I can see what works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see your nginx doesn't listen the 433/ssl.
Your config misses the actual http to https redirection.
Using ip addresses in `server_name` is a nonsense.

You should create two `server {}` statements, one for port 80 and the other for ssl; and redirect from first to second. Your config contains traces of such tries; I don't understand why you commented out all of this. The only thing you missed (if we'll take into the consideration parts you commented out, except last two `server {}`, which are redundant and erroneous) is the actual redirect, you can take it from any of two last `server {}`.

Comment: Sorry by saying I am missing the actual redirect, do you mean..   return 301 https:// example.com$request_uri;? As I believe I also have that in the first listen directive

Comment: I don't see a single uncommented `return`. neither I see `rewrite`.

Comment: Thank you for that you don't realise how many tabs I have open in chrome. 4 from this site and it just came apparent that the issue was because I had 2 server names listening on port 80. Cleaned up my code and it is all working. I marked your answer as solved. Best regards